# dynamic pivot join with table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Having a query with unknown number of rows and a variable as input needs to join to other tables.

I created a StoredPrecodure - FnGetSumScoreHelper(1) returns the table with unknown number of rows. consider 1 as input variable @regionId of sp.
this sp returns the query to be execute and join with other table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpFnGetSumScoreQuery] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@regionId nvarchar(255) ,
@output nvarchar(max) output

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CategoryId) 
                from FnGetSumScoreHelper(1)
                group by CategoryId
                order by CategoryId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @output = 'SELECT PeriodId,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select CategoryId, PeriodId, Score
            from FnGetSumScoreHelper(1)
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum(Score)
            for CategoryId in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

return
```

and here is how I want to join it to other table:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),   
 @SumScoreCategories  nvarchar(max)

 EXEC SpFnGetSumScoreQuery 1, @SumScoreCategories OUTPUT



select [Period].Id as PeriodId, [period].[Name] as PeriodName, 
    RegionPeriodScore.AdminScore, RegionPeriodScore.UserScore        

from [period] left join RegionPeriodScore on [period].Id = RegionPeriodScore.PeriodId
inner join
(
    execute(@SumScoreCategories)

 ) SumScoreCategories 

on RegionPeriodScore.periodid = SumScoreCategories.periodid
```

I know I can't join with sp but what is the solution for joining with dynamic pivot that needs input variable? as table valued functions cannot execute query.

Comment: if i understand what you're trying you can concat query on string and exec full. doesn't use execute on join but use exec on full query.

Comment: I tried exec, it doesn't work. Can you provide an example?

Comment: You can't join on a dynamic query. You need to make the whole query dynamic.